# Cannot get resource or file in Eclipse java project

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, resources, filesystems

I have been trying to locate a resource (a windows executable) from within the same jar file  which I would like to copy to the current directory so that I can use ProcessBuilder to run it.

I have tried many approaches, (class loaders, FileSystem, etc.) but the problem seems to be that Eclipse doesn't behave as I would expect during debugging.
That means there doesn't seem to be a file where I would expect it although it is packaged (I confirmed that).

It would be strange if Eclipse would behave different from normal execution so what am I missing?

Here is what I would like to have working (one of the approaches I tried):

```java
 try {
            File file = new File(this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath());
            final URI jarFileUri = URI.create("jar:file:" + file.toURI().getPath());
            final FileSystem fs = FileSystems.getFileSystem(jarFileUri);
            String pattern = "db.exe";
            PathMatcher matcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:" + pattern);
            System.err.println(matcher.toString());
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Failure occurs at FileSystems.getFileSystem(jarFileUri) which returns null.

**Structure of jar file:**
[Jar file structure text file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/54759511/struc.txt)

**Root structure in bin folder:**
[image]

**New Information**
**The actual question turns out to be:**
Why are some folders in the jar file but not in the binary folder created by Eclipse?
In the Build Configuration the folder is selected for inclusion, but it is not packaged into bin directory only into the jar.
How can I tell Eclipse to also put the folder into the bin directory so that I can access it during debugging?

Comment: To load db.exe from the classpath, assuming db.exe is in the package com.foo.bar, all you need is `MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/com/foo/bar/db.exe")`. When running from Eclipse, your classes (and resources) are not in a jar. They're loaded from the project's output directory.

Comment: I see, how can I tell Eclipse to change that behavior?

Comment: You shouldn't. Instead, you should fix your code in order to load the file from the classpath, without caring if you have a jar or not. Just use `MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/com/foo/bar/db.exe")`: that will make your code much simpler, correct, and running find both in development and in production..

Comment: The class loading is located in /blastindexer/BlastIndexerNodeModel.class in the jar file.
InputStream is = BlastIndexerNodeModel.class.getResourceAsStream("../executables/win/makeblastdb.exe"); returns null alhough the path should be correct.

Comment: No, it's not correct. You can't have .. in a path passed to getResourceAsStream(). Just use `BlastIndexerNodeModel.class.getResourceAsStream("/executables/win/makeblastdb.‌​exe")`.

Comment: BlastIndexerNodeModel.class.getResourceAsStream("/executables/win/makeblastdb.exe"); returns null.

I tried "../blastindexer/default.png" no problem.
"../icons/io.png" --> fails.
Does that mean that I can only access resources on root or in the same directory?

Comment: Post the structure of your jar file (using `jar tvf yourjar.jar`). Post the structure of your eclipse output directory (which should be identical).

Comment: What does the structure of the project look like? Specifically, where is this exe file located in relation to your source code?

Comment: The structure in the bin folder shows essentially what is available in src.
However, the executables folder is on the same level as src and not included in bin for some reason. In the jar it is on the same level as src and seems accessible.
src
src/blastindexer/...
executables/win/db.exe

Comment: It's quite simple actually. Everything under the eclipse source folder is compiled (if it's a Java source file) or copied (if it's not a Java source file) to the bin directory. The bin directory is in the classpath when running your code from Eclipse. So if you want your exe file to be in the classpath, put it under src.

Comment: That would work, but I wouldn't want to put the executables into the src directory. Since they show-up in the jar file, there must be a way to tell Eclipse how to behave properly.